# How to maintain polygon boundary location during overlay in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, overlay, update

I am working with ArcGIS Desktop 10.1 (Advanced license).

I am trying to overlay two polygon layers (buildings and landuse) via an Update overlay such that all building polygons are retained and the remaining areas have the landuse classification.

I want to collapse any areas less than 5 metres in width, and I do not want the building polygon boundaries to shift.

i.e., If there is a 3m gap between the edge of a building and a landuse boundary, I want the landuse boundary to collapse to the building edge.

Does anyone know how to do this?

If I use the Update tool with a 5m tolerance, all boundaries (landuse and buildings) are shifted.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: sounds like parcel fabric management see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Transforming_parcels_in_the_parcel_fabric/00wp00000053000000/

Comment: @Mapperz - I agree, but I haven't yet figured out how to make it work (I haven't used parcel fabric management before, but have played around with it a bit).